# What is the style of Moderat (A New Error)?

Tags: electronic-music, genre

What is the musical style / direction of deep psychadelic electronic music of the style of [A New Error by Moderat](https://youtu.be/JWnX41TBFF4?list=LLpHCRWXWHGyzbqR1ph3VHmg&t=25)?

Comment: Sorry, but to me it's sounds so common in electronic music that I don't find a specific sub-genre to qualify it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specific style of music for this track is ambient IDM mixed with a run-of-the-mill electro beat. Usually that ethereal sounding style of IDM is found in slower and more relaxed tunes like this one below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z49hmBKnIFw

However, Moderat have utilised a faster tempo to compliment the beat. Cool track btw ;)